# How to return ajax response as well as redirection in the views.py Django

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-models, django-views

I am trying to respond to the ajax when it successfully gets login but on the other hand, I want to check based on what user profile, it will redirect to the profile.

Following is my function in views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def login_view(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next')
    email = request.POST.get("email")
    password = request.POST.get("password")
    user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        login(request,user)
        if user.is_male:
            return redirect('/male_profile')
        elif user.is_female:
            return redirect('/female_profile')
        elif user.is_other:
            return redirect('/other_profile')
        data_json = {"error" : False, "errorMessage" : "Login Successful!"}
        return JsonResponse(data_json, safe=False)
    else:
        data_json={"error":True,"errorMessage":"Username or password is incorrect!"}
        return JsonResponse(data_json,safe=False)
```

What the problem I am facing is it only returns Ajax response or redirects to a user-based profile.. but not both together. Can anyone please help me out with how can I first send the response to ajax and then I redirect it to another page in views.py based on the user profile?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you are returning JSON response so you cant redirect but this can be  done as follow:

```
@csrf_exempt
def login_view(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next')
    email = request.POST.get("email")
    password = request.POST.get("password")
    user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        login(request,user)
        if user.is_male:
            redirect = 'male_profile'
        elif user.is_female:
             redirect = 'female_profile'
        elif user.is_other:
             redirect = 'other_profile'
        data_json = {"error" : False, "errorMessage" : "Login Successful!",
                      "redirect": redirect}
        return JsonResponse(data_json, safe=False)
    else:
        data_json={"error":True,"errorMessage":"Username or password is incorrect!"}
        return JsonResponse(data_json,safe=False)
```

in HTML (on client side) on response, success check redirect key  in response and
make redirect
in response success condition add

```
if (response.redirect){
location.href = response.redirect;
}
```

Comment: wowow!! thankyou soo much! It's working as expected. Just wanna confirm Is it a secured way to implement this flow in the live website ?

Comment: it will be better to send csrf_token instead of making @csrf_exempt

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#ajax  this will helpful